# Handling button event in each row of Listview issue

Tags: android, android-widget

I am new to android and am trying to develop a new android app. But I am struggling to siolve one of the problems in my project.

I am using a listview extended from `baseadapter` and need to add a button in each row of thelistview. When I click on the `button` in any row of the listview, I want that it should be removed. However when I do so, some of the other buttons also get removed in the listview.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you..

Comment: Please post the code of how you are removing the buttons.

Comment: really how will you get a help if you post a code?

Comment: If you have time, I think it's worth to watch this ‒ [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70).

Comment: This is what i have done so far for getView() method... I really have no idea how i will do... i i knew  what makes buttons in each row of listview specific i would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an adapter, activity and some sort of data source

In your adapter you attach some data to buttons to be able to tell one from another:

```
public class ExpAdapter extends ListAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                /* SOME CODE HERE*/
        convertViewButton.setTag(buttonId);
        return convertView;
    }
                /* SOME CODE HERE*/
}
```

in your activity you mark button id as the one to be hidden:

```
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            storageOfHiddenButtonsIds.add((Long)arg1.getTag());
        }};
```

and then ListAdapter changes like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            /* SOME CODE HERE*/

    convertViewButton.setTag(buttonId);

    if(storageOfHiddenButtonsIds.contains(buttonId))
    {
      convertViewButton.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

and when you want your adatper to change you, don't forget to call

```
this.expAdapterAllTaks.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Sorry for any errors in my code, but i just wanted to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same type of problem. ListView's `setOnItemClickListener` not works if you add item like a button on every listView item. Solution is use `onClick` in the list Item layout(which you use in custom adapter file) as

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/my_delete"
        android:onClick="onDeleteButtonClickListener" 
        ... and so on />
```

where *onDeleteButtonClickListener* is a method in the activity where you set the adapter in listview.

```
public void onDeleteButtonClickListener(View v) {
// your code
}
```

here listItem means the individual row item of a ListView

---

***Helpful Link:*** [Button in ListView item](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.in/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html)

Comment: But it seams to me all buttons in  each row of listview has same id. Because when i try to get v.getId() it returns same answer to me. i really do not know how i am going to handle this. Could you please be more clear about your solution?

Comment: try this:http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.in/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html or you may search the internet for thid type of topic... it probably will help you. **I get solved by this link** :)