# listview with button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-handler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling button event in each row of Listview issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363366/handling-button-event-in-each-row-of-listview-issue)

I am working on an android app. I am supposed to add a button in each row of ListView and when I click any button I need the button should be removed. However when I do so, button is removed but some other buttons in other positions also removed. Furthermore when i scroll down and up the ListView these buttons which I clicked and removed again appear in the list. 
Could you please show  me an exact solution or a completed piece of code? Thank you...

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            // LayoutInflater class is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listxml, null);
        }


        rawTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rawTextView.setText("Text "+innerClassBookArray[position]);

        final LinearLayout lnr=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutforbtn);

         final Button btn = new Button(getBaseContext()); 
            btn.setText("MyButton"); 
            btn.setId(position);
            lnr.addView(btn); 

           btn.setOnClickListener(myOnBtnClickListener);

        return convertView;
    }   
      private OnClickListener myOnBtnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int posit = bookListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(posit), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        };
```

Comment: google for `ListView with button in Android`.

Comment: use holder class and declare the view in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) is the easy and nice tutorial for you. In this code when on click event try hiding the **button**

```
Btn01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

 public void onClick(View v) {

//Toast.makeText(SearchUser.this, "Button 1 "+listview_arr[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Btn01.setvisibility(view.Gone);
}
});
```

Try like this. Hope its helpful to you. Good Luck

Comment: i have already tried something like that. But some of other buttons also disappered and furthermore  when i scroll down or up the list the buttons again appeared :(

Comment: I am sure if you try that one you will definitely get your result. if not after button hideen call list.notifyDataSetChanged(); and also you must extends listactivity

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this make a Array-list where every element as "0" (`Arraylist<String> my=new ArrayList<String>();` Size of Arraylist should be according to the size of column in list view)and on button click set the "1"
 at the position of like  `my.set(position,"1");` and then notify the list view. also see if condition in the below code
for example

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null){
                // LayoutInflater class is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listxml, null);
            }


            rawTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            rawTextView.setText("Text "+innerClassBookArray[position]);
  Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourid);

      if(my.get(position).equals("1")){
    button.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
            final LinearLayout lnr=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutforbtn);


               btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

    my.set(position,"1");
    ((BaseAdapter)yourActivity.this.lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }   
I think this will definitely help you any question ask me
```

Comment: just copypaste the code i have written

Comment: Nitin Thank you very much.. i solved the problem. really "((BaseAdapter)yourActivity.this.lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();" helped me much thanks to you :)

Comment: if this answer helped you , you can accept it as right answer @Emilla

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) example helps me to fix this :D